# add a menu to my application with android

Tags: android

I created a file  option_menu.xml:  in the directory /res/menu/

I created a file menu.java that contains this code:

```
  @Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
     MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
     inflater.inflate(R.menu.option_menu, menu);
     return true;
}
```

where I can put this code for my menu works?(In menu.java?

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.nelp:
            help();
            return true;
        case R.id.quit:
           quit();

        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

My application contains 4 java files

I Hope the menu to be accessible at any Activity.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want the same code to be run in several activities, you can create a base class that derives from Activity and then derive your own Activity classes from your new base class.  This code would go in that class.

```
public class ActivityBase extends Activity {

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
     MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
     inflater.inflate(R.menu.option_menu, menu);
     return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.nelp:
            help();
            return true;
        case R.id.quit:
           quit();

        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}

}
```

Your activities derive from ActivityBase:

```
public class MyActivity extends ActivityBase { ...
```